# How to print iframe content using external image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to print directly from a url which is a src of an iframe

```
<iframe id="pagetwo" src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/b90ee054017d4ddd25a4c4161127c7d4/tumblr_p8iyzdMhuZ1qzooxpo1_1280.jpg" width="550" height="700"></iframe>

<a id="downloadlink2" class="link_print" href="" target="_blank"  onclick="printDocument('pagetwo')">
  <img src="assets/print-button.png" alt="">
</a>
```

While printing this script:

```
function printDocument(iframe) {
  console.log(window.frames);
  var iframe = document.getElementById(iframe);
  if (iframe.src) {
    var frm = iframe.contentWindow;
    frm.focus();// focus on contentWindow is needed on some versions  
    frm.print();
  }     
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

However when I am putting image in local, then it is working perfect

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is indeed the same as the one described in [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame), but you have a special use-case that may warrant its own answer.

Since what you are doing is to load this cross-origin frame only to print the image it points to, you can create yourself the document which will display this image in a same-origin way, and call `print` on this same-origin frame:

In normal cases, you could just create a Blob of such a document and display it in your frame:

```js
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
var external_doc = new Blob(['<html><body><img src="https://78.media.tumblr.com/b90ee054017d4ddd25a4c4161127c7d4/tumblr_p8iyzdMhuZ1qzooxpo1_1280.jpg"></body></html>'], {
  type: 'text/html'
});
frame.onload = function() {
  try {
    this.contentWindow && this.contentWindow.print();
    return;
  } catch (e) {}
  console.error('in a protective iframe?');
};
frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(external_doc);
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

But since StackSnippet's are themselves ran in over-protective iframes, this won't work here, but it will in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af3b80k5/).

Ps: If you need to support older browsers that didn't supported the Blob API, you could also just append an `<img>` from an `about:blank` iframe: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af3b80k5/1/)